# I think vs, presumably

Tags: difference, synonyms

From [dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/presumably?q=presumably):

> "**presumably**" is used to say that you think that something is probably true

Now, consider the following sentence:

> I think that children should be encouraged to risk.

I am curious to know if it changes the meaning of the sentence if I replace "**I think that**" with "**presumably**"?

> Presumably, children should be encouraged to risk.

I tend to use "Presumably" because I want to express my own opinion without using the pronoun "I".

Comment: encouraged to **take risks**.

Comment: 'I think' introduces your personal opinion. 'Presumably' introduces what any person familiar with the circumstances would assume to be the case. It doesn't fit your sentence.

Comment: You can say "in my opinion/my opinion is" etc.

Comment: If the authorship (and therefore the opinion) is clearly your own, why not simply use "Children should be encouraged..."?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely agree with that definition for "presumably". I think it matches "I presume" better. If somebody asked "Where was Sally last Sunday?" I'd say "I presume she was at church" if I knew she went to church, but the others didn't. I'd only say "Presumably at church" if we all knew that she was a churchgoer.